# SQL Query for checking a particular ID have same date or not

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to execute a sql query so that it checks whether there is a unique date for a id, meaning- a particular id must not have same date.

```
$query = "SELECT PersonID FROM status WHERE Date='$Date'  ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register

    if($count == 0){


         if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO status(PersonID,FirstName,Status, Date) VALUES('$PersonID','$FirstName','$Status','$Date')"))
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('successfully Added ');</script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
            <?php
        }   
    }

    else{
            ?>
            <script>alert('Sorry Attendence already taken ...');</script>
            <?php
    }

}
```

But with this query it does not allow another id to have same date. I want to filter only unique date for a particular id. Another id can have same date.

Comment: Please post some test data and the desired result.  Your requirements are not clear.

Comment: ok i am editing the code

Comment: actually with that query it certainly does allow for another PersonId to have the same date!  we don't know your desired results so we really cannot help you very well updating your answer with test data and results would be good.  Also, the table definition of Status because if DATE has time included it could be part of your issue.  Tag the relational database management system rdbms you are using as well!  mysql, sql-sever, oracle, etc.

Comment: i have updated the code, I want to insert value only if a particular id does not have that date. But the other id can have that date

Comment: Can we have any query as such that it checks whether that id has a particular date or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your first query checks whether there is *any* record on the given date. Instead, you should check whether there is a record with the same `PersonID` on the given date.

Change:

```
SELECT PersonID FROM status WHERE Date='$Date'
```

To:

```
SELECT PersonID FROM status WHERE Date='$Date' AND PersonID = '$PersonID'
```

You should also learn to use prepared statements and parameterized queries because inserting data you get from the client directly into your query is not secure.